# Admin page not working

Tags: magento2, ssl, apache, domain

I setup Magento, however, my admin page is not accessible on the website. Every time I go to the admin page it pops up with 'This site can’t be reached'

Current URL: 77.68.94.254

Any help with this? I think it's due to SSL as I have to take out the s out of the Https when I access the site, however, I can't get a SSL certificate for the IP as that's not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to go to the admin panel of your site, and got a `404 Not Found` error. Is the `frontName` of your admin panel something other than `admin`?

If you don't know the admin panel front name, you can see what it is in the `app/etc/env.php` file. Somewhere in that file, there should be something like this:

```
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    // ...
];
```

Do you have access to the server logs (nginx or Apache)? They may have an indication of what may be going on. Perhaps the admin virtualhost is not configured properly, or there's some other generic error occurring that is being logged with the HTTP server.

I'd also look in your Magento `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log` to see if any information shows up there as to errors within Magento itself that are contributing to this.

And finally, if you have this routed through a firewall or load balancer, you could have crossed wires in how things are connected or a disconnected admin route.

As for the SSL issue, if you're not running this in production, you can easily just run the store under non-SSL for testing / development purposes. If you need a low-cost (or free) certificate for testing / development, I would suggest you look into [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org). If you have SSH access to the server, you install a tool, run a command and it can take care of everything for you (generally).

Comment: Hi Brett, the admin page is 77.68.94.254/admin_1bfc1p

Comment: Right, so I'm getting a "connection refused" which means either (1) the server isn't listening on that port or (2) if you're using a load balancer / firewall connections aren't allowed through. I I would check to make sure that you have your HTTP server and virtual host set up correctly.

Comment: Also check that you don't have misconfigured allow/deny rules on the server for that path. That could also cause this type of response.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please use default htaccess file in root & under pub/static 
Here you can get htaccess file for root-> https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/.htaccess
& For Pub/Static -> https://github.com/emizentech/magento2/blob/master/pub/static/.htaccess